# disable third column of data grid view if first two column having data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on windows form..
I have a data grid view say(3 column).i want to disable third column if i don't have data in first, two columns.
if i have data in first two columns then third column should be enable..

my data grid view like thise

[image]

if first two column have some data then i have to enter some id in third column.other wise i dont want to allow enter id in third column
how i can do this ?
any help is very appreciable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String Cell1=dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
String Cell2=dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Cell1) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Cell2))
{
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
}
```